# WordPress eCommerce plugin for books

Tags: plugin-recommendation, plugin-wp-e-commerce

I am looking for a WordPress plugin or helping resource which I can use to build up a eCommerce website for books which has "View Inside" feature, payments to be handled with paypal.

Heard of anything like that or used something similar? Any ideas how do I go about building an eCommerce site of such scope?

Also any theme which will be a good fit?

P.S. - I am new to building a eCommerce website with WordPress & a bit confused on which are good platforms to build it. What do you guys use and recommend?

Comment: *This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; **this question will likely solicit opinion**, debate, arguments, **polling, or extended discussion**.*

Answer (score 1):

I'm into [WooCommerce](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/woocommerce/) these days. Many features and a clean admin interface. It is quite actively developed on Github. A disadvantage is that many plugins are to be paid for, e.g. table rate shipping or dynamic pricing. Also, the source code could be cleaner. Definitely worth a look nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely worth a look: [Shopp](http://shopplugin.net/).

I think the rest, like preview etc. could be done with simple built in galleries.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-marketplace/ . seems exactly matching with your need

Answer (score 0):

The [WP e-Commerce](http://getshopped.org/) plugin. Uses custom post types, has a whole bunch of payment gateways, postage calculator integration and a whole lot more. My understanding is that it is the best free Wordpress e-commerce plugin around.

There are a lot of other great plugins for e-commerce sites built in Wordpress, but they cost money. If you want a free plugin used by a lot of people and constantly updated get WP-eCommerce. I've used it for a couple of major websites, including a record label website with a complete digital store.